# Bound Mismatch Generics

Tags: java, generics

I have below class hierarchy.

**First class**

```
class First<T> {
}
```

**Second class**

```
class Second<T> extends First<T> {

}
```

**Third Class**

```
class Third<T extends First<T>> {
}
```

**Error line:**

```
Third<Second<String>> name = new Third<Second<String>>();//Compilation error
```

`Bound mismatch: The type Second<String> is not a valid substitute for the 
     bounded parameter <T extends First<T>> of the type Third<T>`

I am really confused with above error. Can you please explain Why this compilation error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T extends First<T>` is not the same as `Second<String>`, because T is bound both to `String` and something that extends `First<T>`.

I have the feeling that you want to use different parameters in Third, doing something like

```
class Third<T extends First<?>> {
}
```

Comment: You could also do `Third<T extends First<?>>`

Comment: `class Third<E extends First<T>> {}` gives compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Augusto is on the right track, but to avoid using a wildcard `?` you could add another type parameter to your class `Third`:

```
class Third<U, T extends First<U>> {
    // ...
}

Third<String, Second<String>> name = new Third<>();
```

The downside is that you have to mention `String` twice in the type arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion in your assignment is that `T` in `Second` is `String` but `T` in `Third` is `Second<String>`. So, in order for the assignment to be valid, `Second<String>` should extend `First<Second<String>>`. But this is not the case as `Second<String>` extends `First<String>`. The following code compiles as expected:

```
public class Test {

   static class First<T> {
   }

   static class Second<T> extends First<Second<T>> {
   }

   static class Third<T extends First<T>> {
   }

   public static void main(String... args) {
      Third<Second<String>> name = new Third<Second<String>>();
   }
}
```